# How to create environment module including java .jar executable?

Tags: environment-modules

I am trying to create environmental module allowing to use java executable. In my case it is called "trimmomatic-0.39.jar".

I want it to be usable via command: java -jar $TRIMMOMATIC [options]

This is my attempt, which does not work as intended:

```
#%Module1.0
    
module-whatis "trimmomatic 0.39"

proc ModulesHelp { } {
        global rkoversion

        puts stderr "\ttrimmomatic\n "
    puts stderr "\tTrimmomatic: A flexible read trimming tool for Illumina NGS data\n"
    puts stderr "\thttps://github.com/usadellab/Trimmomatic\n"
}
    
prepend-path PATH       /usr/local/software/trimmomatic/Trimmomatic-0.39/

prepend-path TRIMMOMATIC        /usr/local/software/trimmomatic/Trimmomatic-0.39/trimmomatic-0.39.jar
```

After loading, if user types following command:

```
java -jar /usr/local/software/trimmomatic/Trimmomatic-0.39/trimmomatic-0.39.jar -h
```

it works as intended, but if user provides command:

```
java -jar $TRIMMOMATIC -h
```

It does not work correctly. Would appreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

The modulefile described seems correct. In such situation, user should ensure module is correctly loaded. It can be achieved with:

```
$ module list
```

If expected modulefile is not found loaded, user should check the available modules to verify this modulefile can be found:

```
$ module avail
```

If the modulefile cannot be found in available modules, the modulepath where this modulefile is located should be enabled with:

```
$ module use /path/to/directory/where/modulefiles/are/located
```

When modulefile is found among available modulefiles, it can be loaded with:

```
$ module load modulefile_name
```

When modulefile has syntax issue, an error is obtained and it is not loaded.

Once modulefile is loaded (it appears in the output of `module list` command), user can check in its shell session the value set for environment variable:

```
$ echo $TRIMMOMATIC
```

If the expected value is obtained with above command, the `java -jar $TRIMMOMATIC -h` command should perform correctly in the same shell session.

Comment: Hi, the module can be found in available modules, is correctly loaded, no syntax error occur. The value of variable displays correctly, but command java -jar $TRIMMOMATIC -h does not display built-in help of trimmomatic-0.39.jar as intended. It also does not work if -h is replaced with actual command line (in which input files, options are loaded). This is why I decided to ask here - because according to my knowledge, I defined the module correctly.

Comment: Could you provide more information on the shell you use and the message you obtain when `java -jar /usr/local/software/trimmomatic/Trimmomatic-0.39/trimmomatic-0.39.jar -h` is launched and work correctly and when you run `java -jar $TRIMMOMATIC -h` and it does not work as intended.

Comment: Sure: echo $SHELL /bin/bash, message I obtain when executing first bespoke command is a help message from trimmomatic, which I would also expect in the case of second command. Instead, I get java help, which is not what I wanted. Also I can not echo $TRIMMOMATIC variable (it is empty; I would expect it to return the full path to this nightmare fuel file). I tried to do the same thing (create module) with other *.jar files and this resulted with the same situation. It happens like it is impossible with *.jar files. How come is that?

Comment: Could you update your question with the command you type to load the modulefile in your shell session. If `echo $TRIMMOMATIC` returns an empty string, it means modulefile is not loaded. If you do a `module purge; $MODULES_CMD bash load trimmomatic`, you should be able to see the environment change that produces the modulefile load.

Comment: thank you for your input. In my case the module was loaded & created correctly. It turns out that the permission settings on my server was non-standard so it prevented from adding the variables to path.